# Combining two one line Perl commands into a script

Tags: perl, if-statement

I am trying to combine the following two one line perl codes into a single perl script that carries out both on a line of a file before progressing to the next line. Note that this is not my own original code, it was very thoughtfully provided here: [Adding a blank line between unrelated data entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14345198/adding-a-blank-line-between-unrelated-data-entries/14345412?noredirect=1#comment19941944_14345412)

## 1

```
perl -pae 'print $/ if (defined $x && $x ne $F[0]); $x = $F[0];' DF-data2pfa.csv >DF-data2pfb.txt
```

## 2

```
perl -pae 'print $/ if (defined $x && $x ne $F[3]); $x = $F[3];' DF-data2pfb.txt >DF-data2pfc.txt
```

The script does exactly what I want it to (compares the `F[0]` field of a line in my dataset to the `F[0]` of the previous line and adds a blank line between those entries if they are different), except I realized that I need it to look at `F[0]` and `F[3]` on a single line and compare both to the previous line. Much to my embarrassment I tried just running one after another, and did not realize that this was adding an extra blank line every time the script encountered the blank line added by the previous script, which is unacceptable to the program I am trying to input this data to.

So I tried using the `Deparse` tool to convert both into script format and than use an `elsif` statement to add the second to the first. This became messy. Also I'm not sure how to achieve the `pae` function of the command line in the script. I'm not sure the `e` is necessary in the script but it seems like first printing each line and then splitting it into an array ( with `pa` ) is a rather integral component to this whole code and I'm not sure how to achieve that here.

Here's what I got:

```
while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    our(@F) = split(' ', $_, 0);
$x = $F[0];
$y = $F[3];
if defined $x and $x ne $F[0];
elsif defined $y and $y ne $F[3];
   print $/ 
}
continue {
    die "-p destination: $!\n" unless print $_;
}
```

I'm also open to not using the `deparse` module if that's unnecessary here. Thanks for any help/explanations you can provide!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's getting a bit wordy for a one-liner, but you could do this:

```
perl -pae 'print $/ if ((defined $x && $x ne $F[0]) && (defined $y && $y ne $F[3])); $x = $F[0]; $y = $F[3]' DF-data2pfa.csv >DF-data2pfb.txt
```

or as a script

```
open my $fh, "<", "input_file_name";
open my $out, ">", "output_file_name";
my ($x, $y);
foreach (<$fh>) {
    my @F = split(' ', $_);
    if ( ( defined($x) && $x ne $F[0] ) && (defined($y) && $y ne $F[3]) ) {
        print $OUT $\;
    }
    $x = $F[0];
    $y = $F[3];
    print $OUT $_;
}
```

I'm not sure that I'm reading your requirements correctly - if you need to print an extra line if either $F[0] or $F[3] matches the previous row, then the conditional would be:

```
( ( defined($x) && $x ne $F[0] ) || (defined($y) && $y ne $F[3]) )
```

Comment: Ah, yeah I probably didn't explain it coherently. I ended up modifying the one-liner you put with the last conditional you listed. Works out like I wanted, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you are doing and so this script may not be exactly what you want, but it hopefully can get you started. It uses the `strict` and `warnings` pragmas which will help you prevent certain errors.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my ($x, $y, @F);
while ( <> ) {
  @F = split ' ';
  if ( defined $x and $x ne $F[0] ) {
    print $/;
  } elsif ( defined $y and $y ne $F[3] ) {
    print $/;
  }
  $x = $F[0];
  $y = $F[3];
  print;
}
```

This implicitly uses the `$_` variable (`while` implicitly sets it, `split` implicitly uses it). It also shows how your conditional statements should look; when not used in posfix style, the conditions NEED round braces. I have left in the `continue` block, but in practice I've never needed to use one, that is probably a remnant of the deparse and probably could go at the end of the while loop (and print can implicitly use `$_` too). Finally the `<>` operator is the magic-open/read operator, it will use the files in ARGV sequentially or use STDIN as needed.

If you need more help just ping.

Comment: you can either pass the filename to the script `perl scriptname.pl file1 file2 ...`, or pipe it in `cat file1 | perl scriptname`. Either will work.

Comment: Its called the 'magic open' property of the 'diamond operator' if you want to google. Also its documented in this section of [perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I%2fO-Operators).

Comment: Gah, I should have realized. Well now I'm passing the filename to the script, however it seems to just be reprinting the entire file, regardless of what I put below the `# do something` comments. Is there a specific amount of indents I need to do beneath the `if` and `elsif` statements?

Comment: I have updated so that my code (should) do the same thing as RickF's code block. And no, like most C-like languages, whitespace is meaningless to the interpreter.